Is there any SDK for azure custom question answering in nodejs?
I am not sure is the right place for that or not, but I am completely stuck about this one, I am currently developing an Azure bot with nodejs and now I couldn't find the SDK of custom question answering in Language Studio in nodejs, I tried the following things but doesn't work for me:
npm install @azure/ai-language-questionanswering
npm install @azure/ai-language-question-answering
npm install @azure/ai-language-qna

Please let me know if there is any package in nodejs or other programming language.
Thank you very much.

Use botbuilder-ai. Here is a sample bot that uses custom question answering.
Outside of using the BotBuilder libraries, I don't see an SDK for CQA specifically (I may be wrong there):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/quickstart/sdk?tabs=windows&pivots=studio
